# Making https get with libcurl

Tags: c, curl, libcurl

I'm trying to connect to a google api.
This works fine in my terminal, there I'm doing: 
`curl https://www.googleapis.com/tasks/v1/users/@me/lists --header "Authorization:  Bearer myAccessCode"`.
This works fine, but now I want to make this inside a c program.
For this I have:

```
    CURL *curl;
    char *header = "Authorization:  Bearer myAccessCode";
    struct curl_slist *headers = NULL;
    headers = curl_slist_append(headers, header);

    curl = curl_easy_init();

    char *response = NULL;

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.googleapis.com/tasks/v1/users/@me/lists");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1);

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0L);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0L);

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, httpsCallback);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &response);

    curl_easy_perform(curl);
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
```

But here I'm just getting a message that a login is required.
I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, is there someone who sees my failure?

Comment: I just realized that I made: `curl_slist_append(headers, header);`<br>
instead of: `headers = curl_slist_append(headers, header);`<br>
So headers was always NULL and I made the get request without a header.<br>
(I edited it in my question above, so the code works, if someone has a similar problem)

Comment: So the question is then already solved?

Comment: yes, but my reputation points forced me to wait 10 hours to answer my own question:-) So I will do it now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like I wrote in the comment above:
I just realized that I made: `curl_slist_append(headers, header);`
instead of: `headers = curl_slist_append(headers, header);`
So headers was always NULL and I made the get request without a header.
(I edited it in my question above, so the code works, if some)