# Resume broken https download in libcurl

Tags: c++, curl, libcurl

I have a binary file to be downloaded and using curl in linux terminal, the following command supports download resume on a broken request.

```
curl -C - -o sample1.bin https://speed.hetzner.de/100MB.bin
```

The above will resume a download that is canceled.

When i use libcurl in my cpp program to do the same, is there any api's that i can use to achieve the above result on a HTTPS broken request.

Thank you for you help.

NOTE: CURL_RESUME_FROM does not have support on HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could implement a retry system by yourself, for example:

```
CURL *curl;
curl = curl_easy_init();
//Set curl options as needed with curl_easy_setopt()
char* url;
int tries = 0;
bool done = false;
while (tries != 3 && !done) {
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE, &http_code);
    curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_TOTAL_TIME, &elapsed);
    curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL, &url);

    if (res != CURLE_OK || http_code != 200)
        tries++;
    else
        done = true;
}
// Check if any error has occurred
if (res != CURLE_OK || http_code != 200) {
    // Could not perform request "
    if (tries == 3) {
        //Too many tries, remote host is overloaded or down
    } else {
        // Cannot perform CURL
    }
}
// Curl succeeded
```

Also you can have a look to [CURLOPT_LOW_SPEED_LIMIT](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_LOW_SPEED_LIMIT.html) and [CURLOPT_LOW_SPEED_TIME](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_LOW_SPEED_TIME.html) to avoid any overhead in the server.

Comment: My requirement is to resume a broken request . Once the programs excecution has terminated when you run the program again, if the URL and file name is the same, it should resume download from where it left . Your code is helpful I case of any error scenarios it will try to download again and the download starts from the beginning .

Comment: I have found `curl_easy_pause` option in the [libcurl](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_pause.html) and an example of resuming an upload to an ftp server [here](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/ftpuploadresume.html), I know you want to resume a download, but it might help or I hope so!

Comment: The same scenario. 'curl_easy_resume' option requires a curl instance which will be lost when the program terminates. We need to resume even if the program terminates and reboots.

Answer (score 0):

How about something "low-level" like passing an extra header? Let `s` be the size of the partially-downloaded file, just use `Range: bytes=s-`.
See [Requesting_a_specific_range_from_a_server](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Range_requests#Requesting_a_specific_range_from_a_server) and [CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER explained](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER.html).

```
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>


int dim=... //size of partial download sample1.bin
std::string s=std::to_string(dim);  // <-- here s is the string representing the size of the partial download
CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();
struct curl_slist *list = NULL;
if(curl) {
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL,"https://speed.hetzner.de/100MB.bin");
    list = curl_slist_append(list, "Range: bytes="+s+"-"); //from where it left off to the end (or where it stops again)
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, list);
    curl_easy_perform(curl);
    curl_slist_free_all(list); /* free the list again */
}
```

Check out also [Making HTTPS GET with libcurl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10210741/making-https-get-with-libcurl.).

Comment: As mentioned in the [https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER.html] the HTTPHEADER is only supported by HTTP protocol and not HTTPS. Hence it cannot be used in my situation. Thank you for the info still.

Comment: I am commenting this after trying the same. And every time the download starts from the begining

Comment: Uhm... looks like the result is the same even if you use curl (or wget) from the command line, so it may be a protocol limitation rather than a libcurl-related issue. However I am unable to find an explicit mention of this.

Comment: From a quick test with curl, it looks like that the URL is also accessible with the HTTP protocol (and it's not a mere redirect to the URL with HTTPS). I did get the 206 Partial content response, but the output (first few bytes) looks empty.